# Pass variables between functions vs global variables

Tags: python

I have a code with several functions defined which I call from a main *container* code. Each new function uses variables obtained with the previous functions, so it looks kind of like this:

```
import some_package
import other_package

import first_function as ff
import secon_function as sf
import third_function as tf
import make_plot as mp

# Get values for three variables from first function
var_1, var_2, var_3 = ff()

# Pass some of those values to second function and get some more
var4, var5 = sf(var_1, var_3)

# Same with third function
var_6, var_7, var_8, var_9 = tf(var_2, var_4, var_5)

# Call plotting function with (almost) all variables
mp(var_1, var_2, var_3, var_5, var_6, var_7, var_8, var_9)
```

Is this more *pythonic* than using global variables? The issue with this methodology is that if I add/remove a new variable from a given function I'm forced to modify four places: the function itself, the call to that function in the main code, the call to the `make_plot` function in the main and the `make_plot`function itself. Is there a better or more recommended way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to define some objects (ie, create some classes) with properties and then pass those objects around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about putting them in a class?

```
class Foo(object):
    def ff(self):
        self.var_1, self.var_2, self.var_3 = ff()
    def sf(self):
        self.var_4, self.var_5 = sf(self.var_1, self.var_2)
    def tf(self):
        self.var_6, self.var_7, self.var_8, self.var_9 = tf(self.var_2, self.var_4, self.var_5)
    def plot(self):
        mp(self.var_1, self.var_2, self.var_3, 
           self.var_5, self.var_6, self.var_7, self.var_8, self.var_9)

foo = Foo()
foo.ff()
foo.sf()
foo.tf()
foo.plot()
```

Maybe some of these methods should be module-level functions that take a `Foo` instance, maybe some of these attributes should be variables passed around separately, maybe there are really 2, or even 4, different classes here rather than 1, etc. But the idea—you've replaced 9 things to pass around with 1 or 2.

Comment: This would seem alot less pointless with *useful names* and/or *collections*.

Comment: @user2246674: Definitely. And it would also be a lot easier to explain concretely instead of having to say "Maybe this, maybe that, maybe the other, depending on the actual things you're dealing with."

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that what you want is a data structure which is filled in by the various functions and then passed into `make_plot` at the end. This largely applies in whatever language you're using.